# Apache Zeppelin - error: overloaded method value run with alternatives

Tags: angularjs, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use the angular binding feature available in Apache Zeppelin in the following code:

```
val ab10 = z.sqlContext.sql("select "+ z.angular("selectVari0")  + " from MyDF")
ab10.toDF.registerTempTable("ab0")

z.angularBind("abb0", ab10)
val selvar = z.getInterpreterContext()
z.angularUnwatch("abb0")
z.angularWatch("abb0", (before:Object, after:Object) => {
       z.run(15, selvar)
})
```

I get the following error:

```
ab10: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [BMI: double]
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
selvar: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterContext = org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterContext@216b8218
<console>:31: error: overloaded method value run with alternatives:
(x$1: java.util.List[Object],x$2: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterContext)Unit <and>
(x$1: String,x$2: String)Unit
cannot be applied to (Int, org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterContext)
z.run(15, selvar)
  ^
```

I tried anther example from [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/27). I got similar errors. I was not able to find any documentation to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in error message, you have to overloaded `.run` methods, with following signatures:

```
(x$1: java.util.List[Object],x$2: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterContext)Unit <and>
(x$1: String,x$2: String)Unit
```

Please, try to call it like this:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
z.run(List(15).asJava, selvar)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your suggestion unfortunately did not work. I get the same error message.

Comment: You could try also List[Any](15).asJava

Comment: Did not work. The number 15 refers to the paragraph 15 that is run on Zeppelin notebook. I am not sure if referring it as a List correct?

Comment: according to zeppelin's doc for this method method ` public void run(List<Object> paragraphIdOrIdx, InterpreterContext context) `: `Run paragraphs @param paragraphIdOrIdx list of paragraph id or idx` https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/ZeppelinContext.java#L442

Comment: you can try `List(15).asJava.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[Object]]`. I know, it is ugly, but I don't have anythig better for now

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. I appreciate your efforts. Do you think I was getting issue because of any configuration problem?

Comment: Good to hear:) No, it is not. This issue is related to signatures of `.run` method. `scala` can't find the method with signature you trying to call and throw an exception